# Getting 404 error while reading JSON file

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to return a JSON file content as it is from web api. Following is my code :

```
string path = string.Empty;
path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
       .Substring(0,AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.IndexOf("HostUrl")), fileName);
StreamReader file = File.OpenText(path);
return file.ReadToEnd();
```

It works fine. But sometimes I get 404 error for the file name. 
I tried to access the file from the generated Url, it loads perfectly.

What could be the reason behind this?

Comment: This code reads text from a local file. This can give you a [FileNotFoundException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filenotfoundexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), not a 404. This has nothing to do with Json or HTTP calls. Please post the code that actually produces the error.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh It comes randomly.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I return the above string data directly through web api and receive in AngularJS. The error comes from our production environment. I am unable to reproduce the error, because the error doesn't come in my local system.

Comment: Check your logs on the production system then. If you don't use logging, add it and log the exceptions. Add ELMAH or Glimpse and try the same requests that return 404 with Fiddler, Postman or any other tools. No-one can guess what's wrong from a (most-likely) unrelated piece of code

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  OK Thanks. We do use logging. I will check the error there and try to figure out the possible reason.